# Displaying two reusable cells in tableview - Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have two custom reusable table view cells in my table view. The first cell, I would like it to be present at all times. The second cell and beyond, are returning a count that is being passed from mysql database.

```
 // return the amount of cell numbers
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }


// cell config
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row < 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! InfoCell
        //set the data here
        return cell

    } else {

    let Postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let image = images[indexPath.row]
        let username = post["user_username"] as? String
        let text = post["post_text"] as? String


        // assigning shortcuts to ui obj
        Postcell.usernameLbl.text = username
        Postcell.textLbl.text = text
        Postcell.pictureImg.image = image

        return Postcell

    }

} // end of function
```

My first cell is there and so are the post.count, but for some reason the posts.count is missing one post and I believe this is because of the first cell. Can anybody help me with this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the value returned from `numberOfRowsInSection` to account for the extra row. And you would need to adjust the index used to access values from your `posts` array to deal with the extra row.

But a much better solution is to use two sections. The first section should be your extra row and the second section would be your posts.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return posts.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! InfoCell
        //set the data here

        return cell
    } else {
        let Postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let image = images[indexPath.row]
        let username = post["user_username"] as? String
        let text = post["post_text"] as? String


        // assigning shortcuts to ui obj
        Postcell.usernameLbl.text = username
        Postcell.textLbl.text = text
        Postcell.pictureImg.image = image

        return Postcell
    }
}
```